# Function call on component stopped working when sibling component gets innerRef

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, styled-components

I have following render section as below. onAddNode comes from parent component and is being used to update state when new item has been added. This function works find if I remove innerRef on Input styled-component. I have tried to find why this happens but could not find any explanations yet.

Does anyone know why this happens? I just want to know why it happens so that I can figure something out from there.

Thanks.
[image]

-- Edit

The Input component that gets the ref fucntion is not a react component. It is styled-component.

My setReference() does set the parameter and keep it in the component. This function does call **.bind(this)** in the component constructor.
[image]

Comment: Maybe it is the same issue as here: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/927 what error message do you receive?

Comment: @Droow I haven't mentioned that the Input component is styled-component. Not a React component. So the ref function setReference isn't meant to pass down to the child component. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ok then and how does your setReference function looks like? Based on this: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/docs/tips-and-tricks.md#refs-to-dom-nodes it shloud work as expected.

Comment: @Droow added above. The issue is not setReference(). It is that onAddNode() does not called when it should if I use innerRef on <Input></Input> styled-component.

Answer (score 0):

Setting innerRef on Wrapper component solved it.